# how Set manual gas limit for specific transaction(using hardhat, polygon test and main network)?

Tags: blockchain, erc-721, gas-limit, hardhat, polygon

how Set manual gas limit when deploying(mint) for specific transaction(using hardhat, polygon test and main network)?